# MLPClassifier only giving one prediction for different inputs

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sci-kit learn for the first time, and have seemed to hit a roadblock when the program is predicting the same response for any set of data. I found a .csv file with many used car listings and have tried to make a model which would predict the price based on the year and mileage. Most of the length of the program sorts the spreadsheet into variable X which contains the year and mileage in the format [[2014.0, 35725.0], [2013.0, 19606.0], [2013.0, 48851.0]...], and the variable Y which is the corresponding prices which are [8995.0, 10888.0, 8995.0...]. These two variables are put into the car MLPClassifier with car.fit(X,y). Using car.predict will always give the same result for any data, which looks like [12999. 12999.] If anyone is willing to take a look at this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

The whole code is:

```
import csv
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier #Neural Network
y = [] #Y is car price, key
year = [] #X
mileage = [] #X
X = []
with open('true_car_listings.csv') as csv_file:
    #Reads the data set and makes lists
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    line = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line < 1000:
            if line != 0:
                y.append(float(row[0]))
                year.append(float(row[1]))
                mileage.append(float(row[2]))
        line = line + 1
        line_count += 1
    #Set X variable
    a=0
    for item in year:
        while a < 999:
            addToX = [year[a], mileage[a]]
            X.append(addToX)
            a = a + 1
print('X is ' + str(X))
print('y is ' + str(y))
#Sorted into X and y variables

car = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)
car.fit(X,y)
print("Training set score: " + str(car.score(X, y))) #Scores the cat MLPClassifier
print(car.predict([[2014, 94550], [2002, 22345]])) #Predicts price based on year and mileage
```

This results in:

```
X is [[2014.0, 35725.0], [2013.0, 19606.0], [2013.0, 48851.0], [2014.0, 39922.0], [2016.0, 22142.0], [2012.0, 105246]..........
y is [8995.0, 10888.0, 8995.0, 10999.0, 14799.0, 7989.0, 14490.0, 13995.0, 10495.0, 9995.0, 12921.0, 12000.0, 7750.0.............
Training set score: 0.001001001001001001
[12999. 12999.]
```

Comment: Your task here is a **regression** task rather than a classification task, so you should probably use `MLPRegressor`. The classifier would treat each different Y value as a different class, and in your case you'd have almost as many classes as the number of data examples. You can also see this from the abnormally low accuracy score on the training set, such a low score means that the model didn't really learn anything.

Comment: @ZecongHu this is correct, and I suggest you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my original comment as an answer:

Your task here is a **regression** task rather than a classification task, so you should probably use [`MLPRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html). The interfaces are largely the same.

The classifier would treat each different Y value as a different class, and in your case you'd have almost as many classes as the number of data examples. You can also see this from the abnormally low accuracy score on the training set, such a low score means that the model didn't really learn anything.